# ReportLab TableOfContent

Tags: python, reportlab

I want to create this type of table of content in reportlab:
[image]

for the time being, I am using reportlab TableOfContent class and it's creating an output something like that:
[image]

that's okay for me but when I am trying to add an entry using addEntry() method it does nothing, here is my code:

```
def table_of_content(self):
        toc = TableOfContents()
        PS = ParagraphStyle

        
        #*************************#

        #***Table of Contents***#
        self.story.append(Paragraph('<b>Table of Contents</b>', centered))
        toc.levelStyles = [
                            PS(fontName=FONT_NAME, fontSize=14, name='TOCHeading1',
                            leftIndent=20, firstLineIndent=-20, spaceBefore=5, leading=16),
                            PS(fontSize=12, name='TOCHeading2', fontName=FONT_NAME,
                            leftIndent=40, firstLineIndent=-20, spaceBefore=0, leading=12),
                            PS(fontSize=10, name='TOCHeading3', fontName=FONT_NAME,
                            leftIndent=60, firstLineIndent=-20, spaceBefore=0, leading=12),
                            PS(fontSize=10, name='TOCHeading4', fontName=FONT_NAME,
                            leftIndent=100, firstLineIndent=-20, spaceBefore=0, leading=12),
                            ]
        # self.story.append(para)

        toc.addEntry(0, "hammad", 1, 3)

        self.story.append(toc)
```

can anybody help me how can I add an entry to this table of content? thanks in advance.

Comment: see the example in the docs here: https://docs.reportlab.com/reportlab/userguide/ch9_other_useful_flowables/#tableofcontents

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `self.notify('TOCEntry', (i, value, self.page))` ?